# How to plot Morley triangle by Synthetic Geometry method?

Tags: geometry, synthetic-geometry

As the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morley%27s_trisector_theorem)

> The three points of intersection of the adjacent angle trisectors form
> an equilateral triangle, called the **Morley triangle**

[image]

So I write this code:

```
RandomInstance[
 GeometricScene[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {Triangle[{a, b, c}], 
   Triangle[{d, e, f}], 
   GeometricAssertion[{c, e, f, b}, {"EqualAngles", a}], 
   GeometricAssertion[{c, d, f, a}, {"EqualAngles", b}], 
   GeometricAssertion[{a, e, d, b}, {"EqualAngles", c}]}]]
```

But I get nothing. Or have I made some mistake?

Comment: I think the task currently is too complex for `GeometricScene`. The following `RandomInstance[
 GeometricScene[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {Triangle[{a, b, c}], 
   GeometricAssertion[{c, e, f, b}, {"EqualAngles", a}]}]]` works.

Comment: `RandomInstance[
 GeometricScene[{a -> {0, 0}, b -> {1, 0}, c -> {0, 1}, d, e, 
   f}, {Triangle[{a, b, c}], 
   GeometricAssertion[{c, e, f, b}, {"EqualAngles", a}], 
   GeometricAssertion[{c, d, f, a}, {"EqualAngles", b}]}]]` fails.

Comment: @user64494 To be honest, I haven't had any success so far with `GeometricScene` for geometric problems

Comment: @user64494 Look the current answer :)

Comment: In light of the answer, I'd call it a bug, except that the answer's code returned unevaluated for me after 84 seconds. Somehow `GeometricScene` is not perfect.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The code is fine with me. Which version are you?

Comment: V13.0 Mac M1 Max. There is a randomness factor; so maybe it fails in some cases, or I hit an edge case.

Comment: @MichaelE2: I can reproduce the answer in 13.0.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: It's 1 for 4 in my trials, good enough to play MLB. And once is enough to claim I can reproduce the answer, but it's not very satisfying.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Works stably for me. Of course, pictures differ.

Comment: @MichaelE2: It should be noticed that `RandomInstance[  GeometricScene[{a -> {0, 0}, b -> {1, 0}, c -> {1, 1}, d, e,     f}, {Triangle[{a, b, c}],     PlanarAngle[{b, a, d}] == PlanarAngle[{e, a, d}] ==      PlanarAngle[{e, a, c}],     PlanarAngle[{d, b, a}] == PlanarAngle[{d, b, f}] ==      PlanarAngle[{f, b, c}],     PlanarAngle[{a, c, e}] == PlanarAngle[{b, c, f}] ==      PlanarAngle[{f, c, e}],     GeometricAssertion[{d, e, f}, {"SameSide",       Line[{a, b}]}, {"SameSide", Line[{b, c}]}, {"SameSide",       Line[{c, a}]}], Triangle[{d, e, f}]}]]` fails.

Comment: @yode: The code from the answer fails with a concrete triangle. Frankly speaking, I think that idea  with `RandomInstance` which results in decimals is a road to nowhere.

Comment: @user64494 I think this phenomenon you've discovered needs to be reported to Wolfram. It doesn't make sense

Comment: @yode: Sorry, don't understand " It doesn't make sense ". Can you explain it?

Comment: @user64494 Sorry about my English. I mean, what you're describing shouldn't have happened

Comment: @yode: This is not a bug, but a serious weakness.

Comment: @user64494 I think it is a bug deserve to report

Comment: @user64494 Just out of curiosity: How do you know the task is too complex for GeometricScene?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks at @Koiadk Grizzly and @yode some hint about this question.
Here we set the orienteering of the angle and triangle and it seems that faster then before.

- **Edit-3**

```
RandomInstance[GeometricScene[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {
    PlanarAngle[a -> {b, f}] == 1/3 PlanarAngle[a -> {b, c}],
    PlanarAngle[a -> {e, c}] == 1/3 PlanarAngle[a -> {b, c}],
    PlanarAngle[b -> {f, a}] == 1/3 PlanarAngle[b -> {c, a}],
    PlanarAngle[b -> {c, d}] == 1/3 PlanarAngle[b -> {c, a}],
    PlanarAngle[c -> {d, b}] == 1/3 PlanarAngle[c -> {a, b}],
    PlanarAngle[c -> {a, e}] == 1/3 PlanarAngle[c -> {a, b}],
    GeometricAssertion[{Triangle[{a, b, f}], Triangle[{b, c, d}], 
      Triangle[{c, a, e}], Triangle[{d, e, f}], Triangle[{a, b, c}]}, 
     "Counterclockwise"]}], RandomSeeding -> Automatic] // Timing
```

[image]

- **Edit-2**

```
RandomInstance[
  GeometricScene[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {Triangle[{a, b, c}], 
    Triangle[{d, e, f}], 
    PlanarAngle[a -> {b, f}, "Counterclockwise"] == 
     PlanarAngle[a -> {f, e}, "Counterclockwise"] == 
     PlanarAngle[a -> {e, c}, "Counterclockwise"], 
    PlanarAngle[b -> {c, d}, "Counterclockwise"] == 
     PlanarAngle[b -> {d, f}, "Counterclockwise"] == 
     PlanarAngle[b -> {f, a}, "Counterclockwise"], 
    PlanarAngle[c -> {a, e}, "Counterclockwise"] == 
     PlanarAngle[c -> {e, d}, "Counterclockwise"] == 
     PlanarAngle[c -> {d, b}, "Counterclockwise"], 
    GeometricAssertion[{Triangle[{a, b, f}], Triangle[{b, c, d}], 
      Triangle[{c, a, e}], Triangle[{d, e, f}], Triangle[{a, b, c}]}, 
     "Counterclockwise"]}]] // Timing
```

[image]

- **Edit-1**

```
Clear[a, b, c, d, e, f]; 
RandomInstance[
 GeometricScene[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {Triangle[{a, b, c}], 
   Triangle[{d, e, f}], 
   PlanarAngle[a -> {b, f}, "Counterclockwise"] == 
    PlanarAngle[a -> {f, e}, "Counterclockwise"] == 
    PlanarAngle[a -> {e, c}, "Counterclockwise"], 
   PlanarAngle[b -> {c, d}, "Counterclockwise"] == 
    PlanarAngle[b -> {d, f}, "Counterclockwise"] == 
    PlanarAngle[b -> {f, a}, "Counterclockwise"], 
   PlanarAngle[c -> {a, e}, "Counterclockwise"] == 
    PlanarAngle[c -> {e, d}, "Counterclockwise"] == 
    PlanarAngle[c -> {d, b}, "Counterclockwise"], 
   RegionMember[Triangle[{a, b, c}], d], 
   RegionMember[Triangle[{a, b, c}], e], 
   RegionMember[Triangle[{a, b, c}], f]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: `RandomInstance[
 GeometricScene[{a -> {0, 0}, b -> {1, 0}, c -> {1, 1}, , d, e, 
   f}, {Triangle[{a, b, c}], Triangle[{d, e, f}], 
   PlanarAngle[a -> {b, f}, "Counterclockwise"] == 
    PlanarAngle[a -> {f, e}, "Counterclockwise"] == 
    PlanarAngle[a -> {e, c}, "Counterclockwise"], 
   PlanarAngle[b -> {c, d}, "Counterclockwise"] == 
    PlanarAngle[b -> {d, f},  
  ...]` also fails. (The whole code is too long to be quoted here.)

Answer (score 10):

Use `PlanarAngle` instead of `"EqualAngles"`.

```
RandomInstance[
 GeometricScene[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {Triangle[{a, b, c}], 
   PlanarAngle[{b, a, d}] == PlanarAngle[{e, a, d}] == 
    PlanarAngle[{e, a, c}], 
   PlanarAngle[{d, b, a}] == PlanarAngle[{d, b, f}] == 
    PlanarAngle[{f, b, c}], 
   PlanarAngle[{a, c, e}] == PlanarAngle[{b, c, f}] == 
    PlanarAngle[{f, c, e}], 
   GeometricAssertion[{d, e, f}, {"SameSide", 
     Line[{a, b}]}, {"SameSide", Line[{b, c}]}, {"SameSide", 
     Line[{c, a}]}], Triangle[{d, e, f}]}]]
```

[image]

Then you can find the small triangle is a regular triangle.

```
FindGeometricConjectures[%]
```

[image]

Which is the Morley triangle.

Comment: It should be noticed that `RandomInstance[
 GeometricScene[{a -> {0, 0}, b -> {1, 0}, c -> {1, 1}, d, e, 
   f}, {Triangle[{a, b, c}], 
   PlanarAngle[{b, a, d}] == PlanarAngle[{e, a, d}] == 
    PlanarAngle[{e, a, c}], 
   PlanarAngle[{d, b, a}] == PlanarAngle[{d, b, f}] == 
    PlanarAngle[{f, b, c}], 
   PlanarAngle[{a, c, e}] == PlanarAngle[{b, c, f}] == 
    PlanarAngle[{f, c, e}], 
   GeometricAssertion[{d, e, f}, {"SameSide", 
     Line[{a, b}]}, {"SameSide", Line[{b, c}]}, {"SameSide", 
     Line[{c, a}]}], Triangle[{d, e, f}]}]]` fails.

Comment: @user64494 Remove `, Triangle[{d, e, f}]` and it will be fine, but I don't know why this triangle thing would crush it.

Comment: @KodiadkGrizzly: Then `FindGeometricConjectures[%]` produces a conjecture which does not deal with `Triangle[{d, e, f}]`.

Comment: `d ∈ Triangle[{a, b, c}], e ∈ Triangle[{a, b, c}], f ∈ Triangle[{a, b, c}]` is elegant a little than those `Sameside`. Just make a note here. :)

Comment: @yode; `RandomInstance[
 GeometricScene[{a -> {0, 0}, b -> {1, 0}, c -> {1, 1}, d, e, 
   f}, {Triangle[{a, b, c}], 
   PlanarAngle[{b, a, d}] == PlanarAngle[{e, a, d}] == 
    PlanarAngle[{e, a, c}], 
   PlanarAngle[{d, b, a}] == PlanarAngle[{d, b, f}] == 
    PlanarAngle[{f, b, c}], 
   PlanarAngle[{a, c, e}] == PlanarAngle[{b, c, f}] == 
    PlanarAngle[{f, c, e}], 
   GeometricAssertion[d \[Element] Triangle[{a, b, c}], 
    e \[Element] Triangle[{a, b, c}], 
    f \[Element] Triangle[{a, b, c}]], Triangle[{d, e, f}]}]]` also fails.

Comment: @user64494 I think you could report the wolfram the case that we cannot get any result when we give a concrete triangle

Comment: @yode: This is not a bug, but a serious weakness.

Answer (score 7):

We can **prove** the Morley theorem by Mathematica.

Without loss of generality,we can assume that `a={1,0}` and `b`,`c` on the unit-circle.

we can divide the angle $\angle bca$ by divide the arc $\overset{\frown}{ab}$ by two points `ca` and `cb` etc.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
{a, ca, cb, b} = AngleVector /@ Subdivide[0, β, 3];
{b, ab, ac, c} = AngleVector /@ Subdivide[β, γ, 3];
{c, bc, ba, a} = AngleVector /@ Subdivide[γ, 2 π, 3];
d = Block[{s, t}, 
   Rescale[s, {0, 1}, {b, bc}] /. 
    Solve[Rescale[s, {0, 1}, {b, bc}] == 
      Rescale[t, {0, 1}, {c, cb}], {s, t}]] // 
  First;(* intersection point of Line[b,bc] and Line[c,cb] *)
e = Block[{s, t}, 
   Rescale[s, {0, 1}, {c, ca}] /. 
    Solve[Rescale[s, {0, 1}, {c, ca}] == 
      Rescale[t, {0, 1}, {a, ac}], {s, t}]] // First;
f = Block[{s, t}, 
    Rescale[s, {0, 1}, {a, ab}] /. 
     Solve[Rescale[s, {0, 1}, {a, ab}] == 
       Rescale[t, {0, 1}, {b, ba}], {s, t}]] // First;
FullSimplify[{(d - e) . (d - e) == (e - f) . (e - f), (e - f) . (e - 
      f) == (f - d) . (f - d), (f - d) . (f - d) == (d - e) . (d - e)}]

β = 50 Degree;
γ = 200 Degree;
Manipulate[
 Dynamic@Graphics[{Circle[], {Dashed, 
     Line[{{a, ab}, {a, ac}, {b, bc}, {b, ba}, {c, ca}, {c, 
        cb}}]}, {FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Blue], 
     Triangle[{a, b, c}]}, {Opacity[.5], Green, Triangle[{a, b, f}], 
     Triangle[{b, c, d}], Triangle[{c, a, e}]}, {Red, 
     Point[{a, b, c}]}, {Orange, Triangle[{d, e, f}]}, 
    Text[Style[#, Blue, FontSize -> 20], 
       ToExpression@#, -1.2 ToExpression@#] & /@ {"a", "b", "c", "ab",
       "ac", "bc", "ba", "ca", "cb"}}], {β, 
  0.1, γ}, {γ, β, 2 π}, 
 LocalizeVariables -> False]
```

> `{True, True, True}`

[image]

Comment: +1. Nice. Also see [that demonstation](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MorleysTheorem/).

Comment: And [that info](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MorleysTheorem.html). As far as I rememder it, your proof is similar to the proof from Coxeter, H. S. M. and Greitzer, S. L.

Comment: A good code is a commented code. Your "etc" is too poor.

Comment: @user64494  Thanks! I have add some labels to this animation. The proof is different from  Coxeter, H. S. M. and Greitzer, S. L. since here we only need the one outside circle instead of three small circles.

Comment: `d = Block[{s, t}, {1 - s, s} . {b, bc} /. 
     Solve[{1 - s, s} . {b, bc} == {1 - t, t} . {c, cb}, {s, t}]] // 
   First;` and `{# . # &[d - e] == # . # &[
   e - f], # . # &[e - f]` need to be commented.

Answer (score 4):

Well actually it is a built-in entity:

```
RandomInstance[Entity["GeometricScene", "MorleysTheorem"][
  EntityProperty["GeometricScene", "Scene"]]]
```

[image]

Comment: The fact that this theorem is built-in rather than easy to construct does solve the problem posed, which is impressive. Kudos, yode. But a different problem of comparable complexity might not be so honored. So this (admirable!) solution does not make the feature any more reliable or easy to use. 

I have often faced similar situations with built-in examples. They help in the short run, only.